# Positioning two UIButton elements in the main view using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I am sure I am missing something very simple here. I am working through the documentation on working programmatically with Auto Layout and I am trying to follow the instructions to put two buttons next to each other.

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    var button1 = UIButton()
    button1.titleLabel.text = "foo"
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    var button2 = UIButton()
    button2.titleLabel.text = "bar"
    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

    view.addSubview(button1)
    view.addSubview(button2)

    var bindings = [ "button1" : button1, "button2" : button2 ]
    // picked this arbitrarily ...
    var opt = NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllTop

    var formatString = "[button1]-12-[button2]"
    var c = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString, options: opt, metrics: nil, views: bindings)

    view.addConstraints(c)
}
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
2014-07-27 01:41:43.597 dynamiclayout[2366:53275] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, 
refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be6fda0 H:[UIButton:0x7be69a00]-(12)-[UIButton:0x7be6d200]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7be74c20 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x7be69a00.midX ==>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7be74d40 h=--& v=--& H:[UIButton:0x7be69a00(0)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7be723f0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x7be6d200.midX ==>"
)
```

I am sure this error message would be helpful if I knew more, but I'm not sure where to begin in parsing it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the constraints programmatically than you have to disable `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

Use below code it will draw the button and instead of setting `titleLable.text` use `button1.setTitle("foo", forState: UIControlState.Normal)` as this is method to set title to button

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    var button1 = UIButton()
    button1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    button1.setTitle("foo", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    var button2 = UIButton()
    button2.setTitle("bar", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    button2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(button1)
    self.view.addSubview(button2)

    var bindings = [ "button1" : button1, "button2" : button2 ]
    // picked this arbitrarily ...
    var opt = NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllTop

    var formatString = "[button1]-12-[button2]"
    var c = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString, options: opt, metrics: nil, views: bindings)

    view.addConstraints(c)

 }
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you for taking the time to write a constructive and helpful answer.